# hibernate default value of transient member

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a transient boolean member that should be set to true when I retrieve the entity from db, but it should be false when I create a new object until it is persisted. After it is saved to db the member should become true.
There is a way to make hibernate manage this automatically or should I do it in the manager?
Hope the following code will clarify my needs.

```
class MyEntity(){
    @Id
    Integer id;

    @Transient
    boolean required;
}

class Test(){
    MyEntity entity1 = new MyEntity();
    assertFalse(entity1.required);

    persist(entity1);
    assertTrue(entity1.required);

    MyEntity entityAlreadySaved = getMyEntityWithID(1);
    assertTrue(entityAlreadySaved.required);
}
```

Comment: You seem to not understand what transient is - it is a way to tell the persistence provider (Hibernate in this case) "ignore this property". So basically you're telling it to ignore the field and then you expect it to look at it anyway. Poor Hibernate!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need this field since you can tell from its `id` if an entity is already persisted or not. If the `id` is `null` it is new otherwise it is not.

You just need a method if you really need it which checks the existence of the `id` field.

In most cases it is recommended to use `@GeneratedValue` next to `@Id` so Hibernate will handle ids for you.

If you really need that field use the `id` field to set up its values either in the constructor or the setter methods (depends on what Hibernate uses).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the problem is that user should see all MyEntity in a table (gui) with a check checked if required and the other unchecked. If one MyEntity is not required anymore user should uncheck and the object should be deleted from db (done in manager).

Comment: setId is never called, and no constructor changes the id. Don't know where it is setted. Anyway I changed the logic. As required is always true but in the crud gui, I set it true in the constructor and I change it only on the beans created for configuration purpose. This solves all my problems. But it's ugly. Proper solution would be removing required as it is redundant. Than the gui should use a proxy that decorates MyEntity and adds required setted with proper value. That field would be managed by gui only and would not mess the server code and puzzle programmers. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Basicaly Hibernate wont handle @Transient fields. So you have to handle yourself.

 by default boolean variable holds false. if you want to set it ture then you have to wirte logic based on Adam answer

 for example

```
class MyEntity{
@Id
Integer id;

@Transient
boolean required;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isRequired() {
    if (getId() == null){
        setRequired(false);
    }else{
        setRequired(true);
    }
    return required;
}

public void setRequired(boolean required) {
    this.required = required;
}
```

}

And you have to handle delete logic seperatly

Comment: Thanks, as commented to Adam's answer I can't do this way, but it's my fault that I didn't explained. Anyway I've understood that I have to manage this.